# What is the best way to map the address on the map and get ETA between two addresses?

Tags: android, google-maps

I very new to google maps APIs. I am trying to create application which should allow user to type a address, then it should show the pin on map. After user presses button it should go to other activity and allow user to type another address, then it should show pin on the map. When user presses a button it should go to third activity and should show a Estimated time and routes based on current traffic.

I have few questions regarding this:

1. Which google API should I use ?
2. Do I have to use more than one API for it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Places Auto-complete API](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) for entering addresses. The API will return the latitude and longitude for the address. You can use that to display a pin on the map.

You can use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for displaying routes between the two locations. I'm not sure if the API supports traffic data.

The APIs have usage limits.

Comment: I am already getting latitude and longitude of the places. That part is done. Now I have to show them on the map. Also I don't want to display routes. I just need to show the Estimated arrival time in my app